# Regex for parsing email body of forwarded message

Tags: php, regex, email, email-validation

I need regex to extract names and email from forwarded email message, where part that I want to parse might look like this(It is possible that some cases are missing, but this would be enough for beginning):

```
<jill@example.com>, "''Steve Pierce''" <steve@example.com>, "Alex" <alex@example.com>, 'Chris Brown' <chris@example.com>, 'Peter Smith' <peter@example.com>, 'Andy McKay, Jr.' <andyjr@example.com>
```

Comment: http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/full_regexp.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
$result = preg_replace('/<([^<>]+)>, ["\']+([^\'"]+)["\']+/', 'person:$2\r\nmailto:$1', $subject);
```